# Orchard CMS Duplicate entry when creating a user

Tags: orchardcms

I have been breaking my head over this. Please take a look at this code. This code is in the customer controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Themed]
    public ActionResult Register(string email, string password, string confirmPassword, Gender gender, string givenName, string familyName, string insertion, DateTime birthDate) {

        ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MinPasswordLength;
        var shape = _orchardServices.New.Register();

        //1. Initialize new content of customer contenttype
        var customer = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("Customer");

        if (customer != null) {
            //2. Define the parts that need to be filled
            var userPart = customer.As<UserPart>();
            var customerPart = customer.As<CustomerPart>();

            //3. Let's validate first if the user can be created
            if (userPart!=null) {
                //shape.Customer = _orchardServices.ContentManager.UpdateEditor(customer, this);
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _orchardServices.TransactionManager.Cancel();
                    return new ShapeResult(this, shape);
                }

                //4. Now validate the user credentials.
                if (ValidateRegistration(email, password, confirmPassword)) {
                    //Now create the actual customer.
                    userPart.UserName = email;
                    userPart.Email = email;
                    userPart.NormalizedUserName = email.ToLowerInvariant();
                    userPart.Record.HashAlgorithm = "SHA1";
                    userPart.Record.RegistrationStatus = UserStatus.Approved;
                    userPart.Record.EmailStatus = UserStatus.Approved;

                    customerPart.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    customerPart.LastLogonAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    _membershipService.SetPassword(userPart, password);

                    var user = customerPart.User;
                    _authenticationService.SignIn(user, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    return Redirect("~/");
                }
            }

        }
```

When this code is run, I end up with two entries for UserPart in my database. One with a related CustomerPart and one not.

Comment: Two users or two records in the database?

Comment: Two records in the database in the table UserPartRecord. First one all fields with data but no corresponding customerpartrecord. Second one with only email field filled in, but now with corresponding record in customerpart.

Comment: Does it also happen if you create the user from the dashboard?

Comment: No. It has to do with my code in the controller. I have changed the code resembling more the code from Sipke. In that case I dont have that problem anymore. But still it would help if I knew what I was doing wrong. In the case of the code above it resembles more the code from the Extended Registration module.

Comment: What I did notice, that if I use the code above which resembles the Extended registration part, is that I have defined my contenttype slightly different. In Extended Registration module it is the User contenttype that gets the profile part attached. While in my project I have the Customer contenttype with the User part and the Customer part attached. So I think I need to find the source of the problem in that.